# How to Create ViewPager with invisible tab bar

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm not sure a ViewPager is the way to go, but it might.
My goal is to create an App with 3 screens.
A main screen and 2 other screens the are reachable by swiping left and right from the main screen.
i would like to have the screens as Fragments.

I have used a ViewPager, but I would like to get rid of the TabBar, and just stay with the swipe.
I managed to get rid of the Tabs, but the bar remains empty. I want it to be hidden.
Is that possible?
Is there a better way to do it ?

If this question was already answered, I have failed to find it and will appreciate redirection as well.

Thanks a lot,
Giora.

Comment: "Is there a better way to do it ?" -- you could get rid of the "TabBar" entirely. `ViewPager` does not come with a "TabBar"; that is something that you (or a template) added separately. If you would provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) -- such as the XML for the layout containing the `ViewPager` -- we might be able to give you more specific suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, it helped a lot. I have used Google's SlidingTabs class. when removed - the tab bar was gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your AnsroidStudio layout screen, go to the "Design" tab. Click on the theme option and select a theme with "NoActionBar.FullScreen" AFAIK ViewPager does not have any TabBar by default.

[image]

Comment: It was a combination of your answer and the fact that I have used Google's SlidingTab class. when using only ViewPager, the tab bar was gone! Thanks a lot for taking the time to answer.